# How to assign values & keys to a string from an associative array (foreach)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to assign a variable to each keys and values of an associate array so I can use it later on in php. The key values is dynamically generated

```
$keys= '';
$items= '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $item) {
$keys .= $key . '<br>';
$items .= $item . '<br>';
}
```

when
echo $keys

item1
price1
unit1
btnsave

and when
echo $item

CFGreen
0.16
each
EDIT

what I want is to assign a variable to each one

```
$item1 = item1
$price1 = price1
$init1 = unit1
```

and exclude the last btnsave

Comment: What's wrong with an array? `$items = array();` then declare `$items[X] = array( item, price, unit );` from here you can access either value (item, price, unit) by its array number ie. `$items[1][0]` will be the item name, `$items[1][1]` will be the price and `$items[1][2]` will be the unit.

Comment: Have you tried `$keys = array_keys($_POST); $items = array_values($_POST);` then `echo $items[0];` (prints the first item)?

Comment: Thanx option 2 so much simpler and working 100%